# How to write multi channel wav file in python

Tags: python, audio, scipy, wav, pydub

I am reading multi channel audio using pydub and I am doing some manipulation to change the audio's loudness. Now I want to write this multi channel audio as a .wav file?

I don't know how to do this. The pydub doesn't support this action.

Could anyone please help me with this?

Kind regards
Denis

Comment: Have you tried at least some of bunch of methods that come up on google search?

Comment: Yeah, I tried to write a stereo file using scipy but it gives uncompressed data. I want to write audio files upto 24 channels.

Comment: http://audiotools.sourceforge.net/ Check this out. It supports conversion to WAV

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can make a multichannel audiosegment from muliple mono audio segments:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

# load individual channels...
mutli_channel = AudioSegment.from_mono_audiosegments(channel1, channel2, ..., channel_n)
```

more info in [the pydub docs](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/API.markdown#audiosegmentfrom_mono_audiosegments)

Comment: This answer wasn't marked as correct, but I tested it, and it does work - more, it seems to be the only Python library in my experimentation and searching that does correctly write multi-channel files.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [soundfile](https://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)'s **write** function.
It expects a numpy matrix of shape (N, C), where N is the audio duration in samples and C is the number of channels.

### Installation

`pip install soundfile`

### Usage

```
import soundfile
import numpy as np

sampling_rate = 16000
duration_in_seconds = 1
num_channels = 2

# Create a white noise signal of two channels
audio_signal = np.random.randn(
    sampling_rate*duration_in_seconds,
    num_channels
)

soundfile.write("output.wav", audio_signal, sampling_rate)
```